# Is there upquote like package for main text and not just verbatim text?

Tags: fonts

This MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{upquote}
\begin{document}

A `set` or 'set' 

\begin{verbatim}
A `set` or 'set'
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Compiled with lualatex foo.tex given the PDF file:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I understand that is how Latex default font works. But I want ' and ` (straight quote and back quote) characters in the main text to also remain the same as in the input Latex file.

The package `upquote` fixes the verbatim text. How would one go about also fixing the ` and ' that show up in the main text as well?

Does one need a complete new font? Which one would that be? Or is there a package like `upquote` but for main text?

I googled but could not find something.

Using texlive 2017 on Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use simply `\textquotesingle` and escaped grave accents followed by `{}`. To make both active characters an easy way is the `niceverb` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}     % access \textquotesingle
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{niceverb}
\begin{document}

A \textquotesingle set\textquotesingle\ or \`{}set\`{}

\MakeActiveLet\'\textquotesingle
\def\textquoteback{\`{}}
\MakeActiveLet\`\textquoteback

A 'set' or `set`

\end{document}
```

The result with `pdflatex` should be:

[image: mwe]

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to put these commands "\MakeActiveLet\'\textquotesingle
\def\textquoteback{\`{}}
\MakeActiveLet\`\textquoteback"  in the preamble instead of inside `\begin{document}` and have them work? I get an error when putting them in preamble now. On windows under Milktex, the package `niceverb` does not exist for some reason. I will try to install it manually for windows.

Comment: @ According to CTAN,  `niceverb.sty` is in the  `nice­text` package of MikTeX.  I'm afraid that in the preamble break something, and maybe also in the body of a complex document. For instance, is not compatible with the `markdown` package ...  IMHO change active characters is a bad idea at least in projects of importance.