# Disable smart (contextual) quotes for entire document?

Tags: xetex, formatting, pdftex, luatex

Is it possible to *disable* smart (contextual) quotes for an entire document? If yes, how?

In particular, can the single quote ', double quote ", and backtick ` be left as-is by some option or method to directly disable such substitutions?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
% minimal document which illustrates the issue.
\begin{document}

Can "double quotes", 'single quotes' and `backticks`
substitutions to any curly, smart, quote, contextual 
be switched off for the whole document?

\end{document}
```

The package [`upquote`](https://ctan.org/pkg/upquote) appears limited to the `\ver­ba­tim` type sections. The package [`csquotes`](https://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) has com­mands and en­vi­ron­ments for user-de­fin­able ‘smart quotes’ *… yet, some switch to just completely disable smart quotes has been elusive.*

The question ["Is there upquote like package for main text and not just verbatim text?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410434/is-there-upquote-like-package-for-main-text-and-not-just-verbatim-text) is looking for a *package plus macros* and rather than an *off switch*.

The systemic impact of *add packages* vs. *toggle a switch(option?)* have intrinsic differences.

On one hand, *"adding a package"* is a *downstream* approach. Downstream files have added cluster and complexity in the authors' files.  [Such as](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410434/is-there-upquote-like-package-for-main-text-and-not-just-verbatim-text/410447#410447), add this package `x` for macro `y`, then add that package `z`, then override `a`, then define `b` so that `b` can then itself be overridden.  Each added package, definition and override also likely adds some computational complexity to the dynamic runtime execution as well.

On the other hand, *"toggle a switch"* is a *upstream* approach. I'm guessing these quote substitutions originate in the various TeX/LaTeX engines. Hypothetically or ideally, a smart quote option switch could be compiled and linked for execution efficiently at the source … with some pseudo logic like:

```cpp
// over simplified pseudo code
if smartQuotesOption == true {
  // make quote substitutions happen
}
else {
  // just skip the substitutions.
  // so, maybe nothing or little to do.
}
```

then conceptually users would use a command line option:

```
pdflatex --no-smart-quotes document.tex
```

or use some direct switch like the following in the LaTeX/TeX files:

```
\smartquotesdisable
\smartquotesenable % default for backward compatibility
```

Such smart substitution enable/disable toggles do exist in document creation environments like various markdown tools, `pandoc` and mainstream word processors.

So, "Can smart quote substitutions just be *toggled off*?" …

If yes, great.

If no, then where would one submit a feature request for a smart substitution toggle? Or, find out if such a feature is already on the roadmap? :-)

Comment: Maybe this question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7735/how-to-get-straight-quotation-marks

Comment: Paul Stanley mentioned it in his now deleted answer, so let me re-iterate in the comments, that technically speaking LaTeX does not really apply 'smart quotes' as they are normally understood (i.e. you press the same button on your keyboard to get correct “curly” quotation marks). It's just that " means ” for TeX and that it has a ligature set up for `` as  “

Comment: I'm kind of curious as to why you would want to turn this off...

Answer (score 4):

I have some reservations about changing the catcode of the `asciigrave` and the `quotedbl` as these characters are often used to change catcodes of other characters. But maybe it's OK.

Updated to work with `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, and `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifxetex}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\newif\ifxetexorluatex
\ifxetex
  \xetexorluatextrue
\else
  \ifluatex
    \xetexorluatextrue
  \else
    \xetexorluatexfalse
  \fi
\fi

\ifxetexorluatex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \begingroup
    \catcode 34=13
    \catcode 39=13
    \catcode 96=13
    \gdef"{\textquotedbl}
    \gdef'{\textquotesingle}
    \gdef`{\textasciigrave}
  \endgroup
\else
  \usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
  \begingroup
    \catcode 39=13
    \catcode 96=13
    \gdef'{{\fontencoding{TS1}\selectfont\textquotesingle}}
    \gdef`{{\fontencoding{TS1}\selectfont\textasciigrave}}
  \endgroup
\fi

\def\smartquotedisable{%
  \ifxetexorluatex
    \catcode 34=13
  \fi
  \catcode 39=13
  \catcode 96=13
}
\def\smartquoteenable{%
  \ifxetexorluatex
    \catcode 34=12
  \fi
  \catcode 39=12
  \catcode 96=12
}

\begin{document}

`Hello'

"Hello"

``Hello''

\smartquotedisable

`Hello'

"Hello"

``Hello''

\smartquoteenable

`Hello'

"Hello"

``Hello''

\end{document}
```

[image: output]