# Apostrophes In Latex

Tags: packages, text

in my text apostrophes are showing as an ascent. The only way I found to input apostrophes is by the command \textquotesingle. But, common, the text will be horrible to read and write needing to input \textquotesingle every single time.

Here what it looks like, the first one looks right, but uses the command, the second uses an ascent to comparison, the third uses a apostrophe but it doesnt look like it:

```
don\textquotesingle t don´t don't
```

[image]

Is there some package I can use to actually use ' and it shows up like an apostrophe? I am writing over this template: https://www.latextemplates.com/template/journal-article

EDIT: maybe that is a font problem?

Comment: A `'` usually shows up as `’` which is the real and [typographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Typographic_form) correct apostrophe.

Comment: It's not a font *problem*, it's just how the font looks like. BTW that the first one looks "right" is an opinion which I bet most people won't share. The third one it the correct one. (That of course also being an opinion, albeit one I bet most people *will* share `:-)`)

Comment: thanks maybe you are right, will stick with the third option for now

Comment: Maybe [Is there upquote like package for main text and not just verbatim text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410434/is-there-upquote-like-package-for-main-text-and-not-just-verbatim-text), there it is suggested to make `'` active to render the character automatically as `\textquotesingle`.

Comment: Similar questions to the one in my comment above are linked from there: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475453/disable-smart-contextual-quotes-for-entire-document?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655954/89417 for LuaLaTeX, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436308/changing-all-single-quotes-to-be-straight-when-within-texttt?noredirect=1&lq=1.