# Typing grave accent for double quotes

Tags: formatting, verbatim

I'm writing a little document on LaTeX to explain how to type LaTeX to some of my fellow colleagues. What's giving me a headache are double quotes.

As an alternative to `\textquotedblleft text \textquotedblright`, I wanted to show them ``` `` text '' ```.
Unfortunately, verbatim *beautifies* the symbols, so they are not keyboard-like. Which is what I want.

I have tried opening with  \ ` (twice) and closing with `\textquotesingle` (twice too).
(See what I mean in WME below.) That gets the proper outcome... despite non-fatal compiling errors.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
\textbackslash textquotedblleft method that works \textbackslash textquotedblright

\`\` the outcome is good, but there are errors \textquotesingle\textquotesingle

\begin{verbatim}
 `` verbatim does not show the actual symbols ''
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `\usepackage{upquote}` for verbatim.

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer for the sugestion.
Actually, looking into it I found another solution that is much to my liking:  
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410434/is-there-upquote-like-package-for-main-text-and-not-just-verbatim-text
Solves my one-time issue nicely and without any aditional packages or new settings, which is just perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for the help!
Following a (different) suggestion, I arrived to this solution:

```
\`{}\`{} text \textquotesingle\textquotesingle
```

which is based on what I found in this [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410434/is-there-upquote-like-package-for-main-text-and-not-just-verbatim-text).

It's minimal and clean, no errors, requires no aditional packages. Perfect for a one-time issue as was my case.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to switch to LuaLaTeX, which does *not* "beautify" the symbols in verbatim mode.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
``Under LuaLaTeX, verbatim-mode shows the actual symbols''
\end{verbatim}

\noindent
\verb+``Under LuaLaTeX, verbatim-mode shows the actual symbols''+

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want `upquote`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upquote}

\begin{document}

\verb|``test''|

\begin{verbatim}
 ``verbatim does not show the actual symbols''
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]